# Can Fabric be used for auto-deploying from GitHub?

Tags: python, deployment, github, fabric

Can I use Fabric to automatically deploy an app on my server every time I push the code to GitHub? (GitHub has the ability to POST to a URL every time I push.)

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  It's not a real good idea, but it's possible.  Just setup something on a URL you control that when it receives the POST from Github, it runs your fabric script.  You could use any sort of CGI/FCGI/WSGI/whatever to do this; even a couple of lines of PHP would be enough to get things underway.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea? I've been hearing this opinion in several places but haven't seen an explanation yet.

Comment: Because the commit is not a good unit of measure for a deployment.  If you start using one as a proxy for the other, you encourage abberant and counter-productive behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There some plugins could integrate to Github. Details : https://developer.github.com/webhooks/

Also, In the Fabric side, you could trigger it by a Github web hook request. If you don't want implement a website to do this, maybe you can try the jenkins and [its plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin).